# How to apply pseudo-element styling to specific class only?

Tags: html, css, placeholder

I have input element in html like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="any TEXT" />
```

And styling in CSS for the placeholder:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: red; text-transform: uppercase;}
input::-moz-placeholder {color: red; text-transform: uppercase;}
input:-moz-placeholder {   /* Older versions of Firefox */  color: red; text-transform: uppercase;}
input:-ms-input-placeholder { color: red;   text-transform: uppercase;}
```

It works fine but,
the problem is that it applys this styling to all input elements to on the page, but they suppose to have different placeholder styling. How I can limit this placeholder styling in CSS to specific class - let's say "**.placeholder-red**" so in HTML I can use it like regular class:

```
<input type="text" class="placeholder-red"any TEXT" />
```

???

???

I have tried something like this:

```
.placeholder-red::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: red; text-transform: uppercase;}
```

and it works, but with **::-webkit-input-placeholder{...}** ONLY (meaning that this styling may not work on the other browsers), but how can I apply it to **input::-moz-placeholder{...}**? I tried things like this -  do not work:

```
.placeholder-red input::-moz-placeholder {color: red; text-transform: uppercase;}
```

Comment: What browsers and versions will you support?

Comment: There is not specific list, just some common ones..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path as you said with `.placeholder-red::-webkit-input-placeholder{...}` it worked well.

To apply to the rest of your CSS support, just do this:

```
input.placeholder-red::-moz-placeholder {
    color: red; text-transform: uppercase;
}
input.placeholder-red:-moz-placeholder {   
    /* Older versions of Firefox */  
    color: red; text-transform: uppercase;
}
input.placeholder-red:-ms-input-placeholder { 
    color: rgba(0,5,143,.5);  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Note that I am using a simple CSS selector: `input.placeholder-red` then applying the pseudo class onto this selector.

Let me know if [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGE/8x35cfat/) worked well for you.

Comment: Wow! That's how you can apply my class to input element right in css! That's great! Yes it worked for me. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: I like how your profile name sits at the end of your comment, so funny